# How to Minimize undecorated stage when taskbar icon is clicked

Tags: java, javafx

I have an undecorated Stage. I would like it to get minimised whenever its icon on the windows 7 taskbar gets clicked. How can I achieve this?

```
public void popStage(Parent view, Dimension d) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(view);

    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

    StageDraggable.stageDraggable(view, stage);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(Resources.getBrickbreaker()));
    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.setWidth(d.getWidth());
    stage.setHeight(d.getHeight());
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972683/javafx-minimizing-undecorated-stage?rq=1)