# Use windows animations on borderless form

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, borderless

Recently I made (mostly out of curiosity) a borderless form. After making my own title bar which includes the title, and the three buttons(minimize, maximize and close), just like every normal Windows program. I also made the code for these buttons (just ask if you want to see the code).

However, I've noticed that there are no animations. What I mean is that, e.g. if I click the minimize button, there is no animation, the program instantly disappears (it doesn't close, the button works, but without an animation). This happens in all cases: When I open the program it instantly appears, when I close it, it instantly disappears.

Is there some sort of way to use these animations that standard Windows programs use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to have the animation effect on a borderless form. However, there are two possible workarounds.

1. Set the `FormBorderStyle` back to Sizable just before a Minimize or Restore, and then back to none aftewards.
2. Use the `AnimateWindow` function instead. The animations tend to happen where the window is currently located. The functions can be applied to any `Control`, not just top level windows.

Here is some sample code:

```
    class FormA : Form {

        private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        private const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
        private const int SC_RESTORE = 0xF120; 
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            switch (m.Msg) {
                case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                    int command = m.WParam.ToInt32();
                    if (command == SC_RESTORE) {
                        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                        this.ControlBox = true;
                    }
                break;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool AnimateWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int dwTime, int dwFlags);

private const int AW_VER_POSITIVE = 0x00000004;
private const int AW_VER_NEGATIVE = 0x00000008;
private const int AW_SLIDE =        0x00040000;
private const int AW_HIDE = 0x00010000;


            [STAThread]
            static void Main() {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Form f = new FormA();
                f.ControlBox = false;
                f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

                bool isMinimizing = false;
                var mb = new Button { Text = "Min" };
                mb.Click += delegate {
                    isMinimizing = true;
                    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                    f.ControlBox = true;
                    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                    isMinimizing = false;
                    //AnimateWindow(f.Handle, 300, AW_SLIDE | AW_VER_POSITIVE | AW_HIDE);

                };
                f.SizeChanged += delegate {
                    if (isMinimizing)
                        return;
                    if (f.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)
                        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                };

                f.Controls.Add(mb);
                Application.Run(f);
        }
```

Comment: Hm, the first solution seems like a simple workaround. I'll also work on the second one and will let you know.

Comment: It works, but unfortunately you can see the original border on the form appear while the animation is playing

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question has been asked over a year ago, but i had the same problem and found a very nice solution.
Look at [this](https://github.com/mganss/BorderlessForm) repo at Github.

**Add FormBase.cs and Native.cs to your project.**

What you have to do is basically to create a Form, f.e. **Main.cs** and derive it from **FormBase**

Main.cs

```
public Main()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        // Redraw gripper on resize
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        // Ability to minimize/restore the form with animation
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
}

// Draw the gripper on the bottom right corner
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - cGrip, this.ClientSize.Height - cGrip, cGrip, cGrip);
        ControlPaint.DrawSizeGrip(e.Graphics, this.BackColor, rc);
        rc = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, cCaption);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkBlue, rc);
        SizeGripStyle = SizeGripStyle.Hide;
}

// Override WndProc to add resize ability -> Cursor
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
        if (m.Msg == 0x84)
        {  // Trap WM_NCHITTEST
            Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);
            pos = this.PointToClient(pos);
            if (pos.X >= this.ClientSize.Width - cGrip && pos.Y >= this.ClientSize.Height - cGrip)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)17; // HTBOTTOMRIGHT
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

I also removed line 147 in FormBase.cs, because my Form had rounded edges
`//SetWindowRegion(m.HWnd, 0, 0, pos.cx, pos.cy);`