# JavaFX Minimizing & Maximing undecorated stage with animations

Tags: javafx, jna

I am using the accepted answer in this question: [JavaFX Minimizing Undecorated Stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972683/javafx-minimizing-undecorated-stage) to minimize my app properly.

However, unfortunately the default Windows minimize & maximize *animations* are not shown at all (the window just appears and disappears).

I know it is possible to make the animations display with undecorated windows, since I have one application that has this behavior (PotPlayer).

How could I make the animations appear with JNA?

**EDIT:** Here's a working Kotlin code piece to minimize a JavaFX window properly, also added bounty.

```
fun makeMinimizable(stage: Stage) {
         val user32 = User32.INSTANCE
         val hWnd = user32.FindWindow(null, stage.title)
         val oldStyle = user32.GetWindowLong(hWnd, WinUser.GWL_STYLE)
         val newStyle = oldStyle or 0x00020000 // WS_MINIMIZEBOX
         user32.SetWindowLong(hWnd, WinUser.GWL_STYLE, newStyle)
    }
```

Comment: I just tested it on win7 and it is animated only with the old style themes.  With aero themes on, or animations turned off, it doesn't animate.  What I can suggest is find the window of the program you say works.  Then just have it print out the window style and try setting it to that in your program.

Comment: Also in your code it looks like your adding styles WS_BORDER and  WS_MINIMIZEBOX

Comment: Oh yeah that 0x00080000 was something I just tried and accidentally left it in. I shall attempt your suggestion!

Comment: @brian Hmm. I tried to set the oldStyle-variable to same as Potplayer has. I didn't attempt to parse the individual styles, but just set the "oldStyle" to: -1764818944. (You can try it yourself). This actually works - the window is undecorated, and the minimize animation does appear, however, as soon as I restore the window, the window is no longer undecorated. Any ideas?

Comment: I just got the same result with potplayer.  There are also GWL_EXSTYLE settings but they didn't make a difference.  Javafx must be do something different but I don't know what.

Comment: See https://github.com/kalibetre/CustomDecoratedJFrame
It fixed the problem for Swing (JFrame) and also for [Compose Multiplatform](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform). May be applied to JavaFX too.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further research on the Windows animations, it looks like a solution could be hacked together. It seems to be more of an OS issue and not just JavaFX.

I was able to get the initial window to stay undecorated while minimizing and with the animation by modifying this in start():

```java
    int newStyle = oldStyle | 0x00020000 | 0x00C00000;
```

But, after minimizing and reopening, the Windows border appears oddly enough.

Then, I tried to use a ChangeListener to swap Windows styles when iconifying.

```java
stage.iconifiedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
            if (t1.booleanValue() == true) {
                int newStyle = oldStyle | 0x00020000 | 0x00C00000;
                user32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, newStyle);
            } else if (t1.booleanValue() == false) {
                int newStyle = oldStyle | 0x00020000;
                user32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, newStyle);
            }
        }
    });
```

This successfully gets the windows un-minimize animation to work fine consistently, while leaving the (visible) stage borderless.

It looks like I can get minimization animations working once I find out the best way to re-apply:

```java
    int newStyle = oldStyle | 0x00020000 | 0x00C00000;
    user32.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, newStyle);
```

just before the stage is iconified, and the border isn't visible to the user. Once implemented, this might work similarly to the C# solution in the first link below. Basically, what the above ChangeListener does in reverse.

I think we need another thread listening in the background to finish up this solution, waiting for the iconified event to happen. I think stage.isIconified() == false should be the case when the event is fired, and then we execute the necessary task in the background thread to set the above code. Then, the (...somewhat working) changeListener will reset it back to a non-framed Window without animations, when un-minimizing, until it is minimized again.

There is a minor bug with the first un-minimize displaying the bottom portion of my stage clipped and duplicated a little bit, but it disappears after subsequent actions. We may need to try changing the second hexadecimal to something else that triggers animations, and setting everything outside of the ChangeListener and in another thread.

I plan to finish this up soon in my own fx program. I'm still a student so I'm not too experienced with multithreading and services but I have a good idea on how to go about it, it will just take a few hours of hacking away.

Let me know if you make any progress in the meantime! This is a good starting point. Nobody has solved this issue in Java yet. I was reading up on some discussions that borderless programs like Steam have done this, but I don't think anyone could entirely figure out how they accomplished it, I doubt it was through the C# hack below. But, it's good enough for our purposes.

*Links to do with solving borderless/undecorated animations:*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31489766/7234125

**^ We need to implement this answer, option #1, from C# to Java**

[Borderless Window Using Areo Snap, Shadow, Minimize Animation, and Shake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765561/borderless-window-using-areo-snap-shadow-minimize-animation-and-shake)

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/Window%20styles.html