# WindowState and the Maximum/Minimize buttons Event are different

Tags: c#, winforms

Before starting the question, I apologize for not using English well.

---

I don't want to use Border and Minimized/Maximized/Closed buttons in the existing form.

```
FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Then, I created Custom Minimized/Maximized/Closed Button.

```
        //Closed
        private void imgLblCloseProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            this.Close();
        }
        //Maximized
        private void imgLblMaximumProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized) {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            } else if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal) {
                //this.MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea;   //★★★
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;                           //
            }
        }
        private void tbPnlTopBar_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            imgLblMaximumProgram_Click(imgLblMaximumProgram, e);
        }
        //Minimized
        private void imgLblMinimumProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;                               //
        }
```

When Clear the annotation, Maximizes without taking up space on the taskbar.
However, **if more than one monitors are used, they do not work on screens other than the main screen.**

In addition, for the Maximized/Minimized button, there seems to be a built-in animation provided by Windows.
When the Maximized/Minimized was changed via FormWindowState, I confirmed that the animation did not work.

---

The biggest reason why I want the Low-cost Maximized Button Event is that when I use more than one monitors, I have a **issue**.
Therefore, I need a way to maximize the form while displaying TaskBar on two or more monitors.

p.s. I want the animation of the maximized/minimized button as well, so the best way to run the maximized/minimized button's event is.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't want to cover the taskbar when the form is maximized, correct? If so, use `this.MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea;`.

Comment: As to your second question, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31473489/8967612) (please be aware that you should ask one question per post though).

Comment: **when I use more than one monitors, I have a issue(they do not work on screens other than the main screen).**  @41686d6564

Comment: In the case of animation, the Border of Sizable is visible in a short moment when the FormStyle has changed.

Comment: The reason why anime disappears has become clear. The border itself contains animation when maximizing/minimizing changes. Thus, under FormBorderStyle == None, the animation effect may well disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.
*when I use more than one monitors, I have a issue(they do not work on screens other than the main screen).*

If you still want to use FormWindowState.Maximized on more than one monitor, this is likely to be an appropriate solution.

```
this.MaximizedBounds = new Rectangle(new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Y), new Size(Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea.Width, Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle).WorkingArea.Height));
```

However, there is an **error** on the **screen with higher resolution than the main monitor**.