# JavaFX (Windows): Undecorated window isIconified not updated when un-minimized

Tags: java, windows, javafx, javafx-8, jna

I have made an undecorated window, and I have used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27254024/2970960) as a reference in order to make it minimizable when the user clicks on the taskbar icon. I have mainly used the "simplest" version in the answer, and it is working.

Recently, I have discovered one problem; although I can minimize/un-minimize the window by clicking on the taskbar icon, but the `iconifiedProperty` does not change its value when the window is un-minimized - the Stage needs to receive another layout change (e.g. `setMaximized(true)`) in order for `iconifiedProperty` to transit to `false` state.

I need to detect this change because I am also making the window not to be full-screen when it is maximized (See this [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133330), it includes a temporary workaround). Again, I can make the size of the maximized window take the full visual bounds of the screen, but when a maximized window is minimized and subsequently un-mininized, the window will revert to covering the taskbar (full-screen).

Any help would be appreciated.

### Edit

An update on the problem. I just realized that `iconifiedProperty` does not change only when the window is in maximized state.

I.e.

1. Window is at maximized state.
2. Window is minimized (no matter via `setIconified(true)` or click of taskbar icon).
3. Window is un-minimized by clicking on taskbar icon.

This will cause `iconifiedProperty` to transit to `true` in step 2, and will not go back to `false` in step 3. Thereafter, repeating step 2 and 3 will not cause in the change of this property either.

This problem is not observed to happen if the window is not in maximized state, though.

### Edit 2

Further testing shows that it has nothing to do with being undecorated - the iconified property change does not happen even on a normal maximized window.

Comment: Can you use window resize events?

Comment: @technomage Thanks, I added listener to `heightProperty` and it seems like this value is changed when the screen is forced back to being full screen.

Comment: You may need to respond heuristically.  I've traditionally found a lot of bugs/inconsistencies around keeping Java windows' metadata in synch with that of their native counterparts.